# Add event listener to dropdown list dynamically in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am updating an ASP.NET web site the Framework is 2.0.  It is written in VB. I create a dropdown list and populate it dynamically.  That is working.  I need to add an event, onselectchange() to the dropdown.  This event will change menu items.
This is the method creates the dropdown and populates it:

```
Public Sub ListLocations()
 Dim facilityValueSelected As String = ""

 'Get all of the facility service types from the database
 'The stored procedure is ordered by ID. 
  GetServiceTypes()

 Response.Write("<div style='text-align:left;'>")
 Response.Write("<label>Facility Type:<select id='FacilityTypeDDL' name='FacilityTypeDDL' size='1' runat='server'>")

For Each facility As ListItem In lstBoxFacilityTypes
   'Get the first value in the list and use the ID to to the list of locations below
   If String.Compare(facilityValueSelected, "") = 0 Then
       facilityValueSelected = facility.Value
   End If
   Response.Write("<option value=''" & facility.Value & "''>" & facility.Text & "</option>")
Next

Response.Write("</select></label>")
Response.Write("</div>")
End Sub
```

How do I add an event to this dropdownList when the user changes selections?  I want the event to be handled in the code-behind so I can make a call to the database.

**UPDATE**
I added the 'onchange' event to the dropdown but it is not firing in the code behind.  This is my changes:

```
Response.Write("<label>Facility Type:<select id='FacilityTypeDDL' name='FacilityTypeDDL' size='1' runat='server' onchange='UpdateLocationList()' autopostback='true'>")
```

This is the method I added to the code behind:
I put a breakpoint in this method at the event does not fire.

```
 Public Sub UpdateLocationList()
    Dim strFacilityValue As String = ""
    'Get selected Service Type
    strFacilityValue = "3"
    'Populate Menu List
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
Added the function to the dropdown:

```
  Response.Write("<label>Facility Type:<select id='FacilityTypeDDL' name='FacilityTypeDDL' size='1' onchange='UpdateLocationList();' autopostback='true'>")
```

Added the javascript function below in the aspx page.  The alerts do not show when the selection is changed.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateLocationList(obj) {
        alert('In function');
        var facilityValue = document.getElementById("FacilityTypeDDL").value;
        alert(facilityValue);
        __doPostBack('FacilityTypeDDL', facilityValue);
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
ASPX page

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Locations.aspx.vb" Inherits="Editor_Locations" %>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateLocationList(obj) {
        alert('In function');
        var facilityValue = document.getElementById("FacilityTypeDDL").value;
        alert(facilityValue);
        __doPostBack('FacilityTypeDDL', facilityValue);
    }
</script>
<%ListLocations()%>
```

**UPDATE**

I am getting the error: ReferenceError: UpdateLocationList is not defined.  This is my javascript code:

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Locations</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
    <script src = "scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>   
    <script  type="text/javascript">     
        function UpdateLocationList(obj) {
            alert('In function');
            var facilityValue = document.getElementById("FacilityTypeDDL").value;
            alert(facilityValue);
            __doPostBack('FacilityTypeDDL', facilityValue);
        }     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<%ListLocations()%>
</body>
```

Comment: set the autopostback property to true

Comment: OK. How to add the event itself?

Comment: Use onchange and do postback on OnChange event. please refer http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/270253/HTML-Select-Control-Needs-to-Postback-in-asp-net

Comment: I tried adding the onchange event to the dropdown list but it is not firing.  I added my code above.

Comment: Please refer the link that i posted. you need to do postback on onchange. You need to write Onchange event in aspx page and from there fire postback event!! or else you can use asp.net dropdown itself instead of HTML select and use onselectedindexchanged event on asp dropdown

Comment: I have tried to follow the example on the link.  it is not working.  The javascript function is not firing.  I will put my code above.

Comment: are you able to see the dropdown on the page itself?

Comment: Yes.  The dropdown is available and populated. When I change the value in the dropdown, the alert in the javascript function should show.

Comment: where do you have call to this function ListLocations() ? I think you need to add controls inside OnInit method as its dynamically created u need to call it on page_initialization event.

Comment: ListLocations() is called from the .aspx page.  I will add code aspx page above.

Comment: Do you mean the Page_Load event?

Comment: override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e) in c# and Vb something similar to this.

Comment: ok. I added your code to my page under !isPostback inside page load event and i m getting alert msg!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76580/discussion-between-yog2411-and-gloria-santin).

Comment: I am getting a ReferenceError when the javascript function is called.  I added my javascript above.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the javascript function, UpdateLocationList(), to a separate .js file and it was triggered.